# Why does my function for multiples returns NaN?

Tags: javascript

I want my function to add all 3 and 5 multiples for a given number. My code

```
function solution(number) {
  const multiples = [3, 5];
  let result;

  for (let i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    if (i % multiples[0] === 0 || i % multiples[1] === 0) {
      result += i;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
console.log(solution(49));
```

Got

```
NaN
```

What is wrong with my function scope?

Comment: The code adds some numbers to `result` in the loop but what is its initial value?

Comment: Typing this question: 30+ seconds. Finding answer by using a debugger: ~20 seconds. I don't understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because initial value of `result` is `undefined`:

You can do: `let result = 0;`

```js
function solution(number) {
  const multiples = [3, 5];
  let result = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    if (i % multiples[0] === 0 || i % multiples[1] === 0) {
      result += i;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
console.log(solution(49));
```

Answer (score 1):

Initialize `result` to 0. By default, it's `undefined`.

So your

`result += i` ends up to be (for the first time)

`result = undefined + i` which is `NaN` and further on subsequent additions it's just a bunch of `NaN + i` operations which again is equivalent to `NaN`.